# Verifiable Delay Function: Trusted Setup

Tags: rsa, group-theory

The [Efficient Verifiable Delay Function paper](https://eprint.iacr.org/2018/623.pdf) suggested that there are two ways to construct the group. One of them requires a trusted setup in the sense that whoever constructs the RSA unknown group order needs to destroy the factors otherwise fake proofs of exponentiations can be constructed.

Another way is using a class group of imaginary quadratic fields. However, the paper didn't give an example of how it can be used. Is everything else except this step the same, or does it require different proof verification?

Comment: Problems with verifiable delay functions include 1) the intended delay can be shrunk by a sizable factor (like 10) using specialized fast hardware (it can't be parallelized, though). 2) energy cost is proportional to delay. For these reasons, they are never used in practice AFAIK [update: now I know better, see below].

Comment: @fgrieu they are used in Chia, for example ([link](https://docs.chia.net/docs/03consensus/vdfs/)).

Answer (score 1):

The paper actually explains how to sample parameters for the class group setting [on page 9](https://eprint.iacr.org/2018/623.pdf). Everything else is oblivious of the particular choice of the hidden order group. The description given in the paper is not specific to RSA groups and can be instantiated identically in the class group setting.

Note that the low order assumption does not hold in class groups where the discriminant is a Mersenne prime as was shown by [Belabas et al](https://eprint.iacr.org/2020/1310.pdf). In groups where the low order assumption does not hold, the instantiated VDF is insecure. This is an extremely small subset of primes, however, one might be tempted to apply them due to performance considerations.